# Hash function C

Tags: c, ascii, hashtable

I am having trouble implementing my hash function for my hash table.

I want to hash my words such that A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, and so on.  The position of the letter in the word is irrelevant, since we will consider permutations of the word.  Moreover, the case of the letter will be irrelevant in this problem as well, so the value of a = the value of A = 1.

And for strings, abc = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6, bc = 2 + 3 = 5, etc.

And for cases where ab = 3 and aaa = 3, I have already had a way to handle that situation. Right now I just want to get the hash value.

The problem I am having right now is that aaa is giving me 1, and ab is giving me 2.

Below is my code:

```
int hash(char *word)
{
   int h = 1;
   int i, j;

   char *A;
   char *a;
   // an array of 26 slots for 26 uppercase letters in the alphabet
   A = (char *)malloc(26 * sizeof(char));
   // an array of 26 slots for 26 lowercase letters in the alphabet
   a = (char *)malloc(26 * sizeof(char));

   for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
      A[i] = (char)(i + 65); // fill the array from A to Z
      a[i] = (char)(i + 97); // fill the array from a to z
   }

   for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
      //printf("HIT\n");
      for (j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
         // upper and lower case have the same hash value
         if (word[i] == A[j] || word[i] == a[j]) {
            h = h + j; // get the hash value of the word
            //printf("HIT 2\n");
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   printf("H: %d\n", h);

   return h;
}
```

Comment: There's still the free missing...

Comment: You do know about [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) and [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper)? No need for two arrays or checks. Any since you have a fixed alphabet, why allocate dynamically at all?

Comment: Actually, I don't see the reason for the arrays at all, why not just simply add the letters number (which you can get from e.g. `tolower(word[i]) - 'a' + 1`). Also, what will happen if you have non-letter characters in the words?

Comment: That actually makes me think...
I mean there are other approaches out there
I just started learning C so I am doing this to make things simple

Comment: You can keep it simple as @JoachimPileborg suggested by using the functions in `ctype.h` for character classification, etc. **1** array instead of **2** is always simpler. But in upper/lower case conversion, you don't even need functions. lowercase char codes are just `32` greater than upper and vice versa.  Have a look at [**ASCII Table and Description**](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: You really should read up on hashing.  http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx may be of use, I found it illuminating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that changing

```
int h = 1;
```

to

```
int h = 0;
```

and

```
h = h + j;
```

to

```
h = h + j + 1;
```

will fix the issue.

---

The one other problem is that you forgot to free the `malloc`ed memory. Also, there is [no need to cast the result of `malloc`](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)(and family) in C.

This

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
```

will call `strlen` in every iteration of the loop. This will reduce the performance of your program. Use

```
int len = strlen(word);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

instead, which is much faster as `strlen` isn't called in every iteration. Lastly, `sizeof(char)` is 1. So you can omit it.

Comment: You should add the missing free calls, otherwise the code is still wrong.

Comment: Added some more details.

Answer (score 2):

change `h=h+j` to h=`h+j+1`
and `h=1` to `h=0`.

Also you should free the allocated memory so include these lines just before return:

```
free(A);
free(a);
```

However I don't understand why so complicated code was written for such a simple task.

A much simpler code can be written:

```
int hash(char *word)
{
   int sum=0;
   while(*word != '\0')
   {

       if(*word >='A' && *word < 'A'+26)
            sum=sum+(*word -'A' + 1);
       else if(*word >='a' && *word < 'a'+26)
            sum=sum+(*word -'a' + 1);
       else
            return -1;

       word++;
   }

   return sum;
}
```

Comment: This is my first time dealing with ascii numbers. But thanks a lot!

Comment: If would be clearer if you used e.g `'A'` instead of `65`.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple issues:

1. You still aren't freeing the arrays you allocated
2. Initial value of 1 for h makes no sense
3. You add the index to the hash. 'A' and 'a' are at index 0, so you're adding 0 in that case (so no matter how many 'a' s you give your code will return 1)
4. Why a dynamic array? You know the size, it isn't going to change. You could use

   ```
   char A[26];
   char a[26]; // you can also add initialisation, e.g. = {'a', 'b', ...
   ```
5. Why an array in the first place?

So, [here](http://ideone.com/JHPIFG) is the quick fix, staying close to your code.

Taking all of the above into account, you could simplify to:

```
int hash(char const * string) {
  int h = 0;
  for (; *string; ++string) {
    int index = tolower(*string) - 'a' + 1;
    if ((index > 0) && (index < 27)) {
      h += index;
    }
  }
  return h;
}
```

[Live](http://ideone.com/50rgXm)

---

When only hashing words with non special characters, you need to handle ignored words in the caller somehow.

```
char hash(char const * string, int * h) {
  *h = 0;
  for (; *string; ++string) {
    int index = tolower(*string) - 'a' + 1;
    if ((index > 0) && (index < 27)) {
      *h += index;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

That way you can use the return value to test if the word should be ignored.

Comment: How do you handle special characters though?

Comment: I ignore them, like in your original code. Do you want to handle them?

Comment: Oh so when I try your code it gave me 69 for études for some reasons.

Comment: T = 20, U = 21, D = 4, E = 5, S = 19; summing up gives 69, which is what was expected. é is a special character, so it has been ignored.

Comment: My bad I made a mistake in my calculation.
But what if I want to ignore the whole word instead of just a character?